# Extract the inner text of the anchor elements correctly using R

Tags: r, xpath

I am using R to scrape the link titles in this link www.jamesaltucher.com/sitemap.xml

This is my code.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
url.link <- 'http://www.jamesaltucher.com/sitemap.xml'
blog <- getURL(url.link)
blog          <- htmlParse(blog, encoding = "UTF-8")
titles  <- xpathSApply (blog ,"//a",xmlValue)             ## titles
```

My `titles` is an empty list.

See the screenshot:

[image]

Did I use the xpath incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are looking for `loc` element and not `a` element.

```
titles  <- xpathSApply (html ,"//loc",xmlValue)
```

Comment: loc? I want to get the inner html of `<a href="somelink">inner html here</a>` Wouldn't that require me to state `a`?

Comment: Your answer is right. But I am not sure `loc` is the correct answer. Can help to explain?

Comment: I meant I am not sure *WHY* `loc` is correct. I am confused by that term. Sorry for the missing word.

Comment: Check content of the htmldoc.. the links are inside `<loc>` tags and not `<a>` tags

Comment: I opened the link `www.jamesaltucher.com/sitemap.xml` inside a browser. Maybe that is why it is `<a>` tag. Can I check the htmldoc inside the RStudio?

Comment: Just see output of `getURL(url.link)` inside R session.

Comment: When I left click on the `blog` on the right hand side, I just see a pointer. How do I see the output of `blog`? See attached http://grab.by/rR2W

Comment: just type `blog` in your R prompt and hit enter

Answer (score 0):

web_page <- readLines("http://vueloeyewear.com/shop/retro/black-cia/")

author_lines <- web_page[grep("strong", web_page)]

author_lines <- author_lines [7:15]

test <- gsub(", ","",toString(author_lines))

test <- gsub("
","

",test)

author_lines <-  htmlParse(test)

xpathSApply (author_lines,"//p",xmlValue)

Look at this one, //Loc means the actual tag ..